# how to price barrier option under local vol model using QuantLib

Tags: local-volatility, barrier, finite-difference-method

I use QuantLib in Python. Now I have implied volatility surface data. How can I get the local vol surface than using finite difference method to price a barrier option in QuantLib?

Comment: I use BlackVarianceSurface to get the implied vol surface. Then use LocalVolSurface to get the local vol surface. When using GeneralizedBlackScholesProcess, I don't know how to use the local vol surface.

Comment: In GeneralizedBlackScholesProcess, the model looks like this - dlnS(t)=(r(t)−q(t)−σ(t,S))dt+σdWt. However, I want the sigma before dWt to be local, no constant. ALso, I found that in Python, GeneralizedBlackScholesProcess can only use blackvol but not local vol surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a cursory look, the `FdBlackScholesBarrierEngine` seems to do what you want; when the `localVol` parameter is set to `true`, it will use the local volatility contained in the passed process. I'd suggest you to check the code, though.

As a further note: the `GeneralizedBlackScholesProcess` class converts the Black volatility to the local one internally (see [the code here](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/ql/processes/blackscholesprocess.cpp#L179)) so you might not need to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanna know how The **GeneralizedBlackScholesProcess** class converts the Black volatility to local one internally. I am new to QuantLib. In the parameters list, I need to input blackVolTS and localVolTS. Currently I only know **BlackConstantVol**. Is there any other kind blackvol in QuantLib?

Comment: One constructor takes Black vol and local vol; the other doesn't.

Comment: The conversion is at https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/ql/processes/blackscholesprocess.cpp#L179

Comment: But when I use the constructor taking Black vol and Local vol, the model is under this one - d\ln S(t) = (r(t) - q(t) - \frac{\sigma(t, S)^2}{2}) dt  + \sigma dW_t.. I wanna price the option under this one - dSt = rStdt + σ(t,St)Std_Wt. Can I do that in the QuantLib?

Comment: No, the implementation of the BS process is based on log(S).

Comment: Or can I price the option under this one -  d\ln S(t) = (r(t) - q(t) - \frac{\sigma(t, S)^2}{2}) dt + \sigma(t, S) dW_t.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure comments are working for this.  May you edit your question and expand it to clarify exactly what you're trying to do, and with which pricing engine?

Comment: I wanna price a down-out put barrier option. I have implied vol surface and I get local vol surface. The stock price follows a log-normal distribution where sigma is local. dS/S = (r - q)*dt + sigma(S,t) * dBt , which is the same as d\ln S(t) = (r - q - \frac{\sigma(t, S)^2}{2}) dt + \sigma(t, S) dW_t. That's what I am trying to do by using QuantLib.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check it tomorrow when I go to work. I think there is some difference between Quantlib in python and c++. I will try to use C++ version.

Comment: This is the code that I wrote. (https://pan.baidu.com/s/1VGoYMvUlBbnkzZF4uRIhtg) I try to price the option under local vol model d\ln S(t) = (r - q - \frac{\sigma(t, S)^2}{2}) dt + \sigma(t, S) dW_t. I get the price from bloomberg which is around 55, and I wrote my own code in python, including generating local vol and finite difference, and then I get a price close to 55. However, when I use the code in that web to price the down-out put barrier option, I get a price wihch is quite large, more than 100. I don't know where I get wrong.

Comment: I suggest you take this to the QuantLib mailing list.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this while trying to debug a similar issue in Python. It looks as though `GeneralizedBlackScholesProcess` has a public method `localVolatility()` which exposes the internally used instantaneous vol (see Luigi's link above), but it's not exposed via Python. I think this would be a great addition to help with debugging, I'll submit a pull request to add.